# Docker Compose java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect cannot be cast to class java.sql.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem about fixing the issue in docker-compose.yml file.
I have a problem about connection between service and database.

Here is my issue shown below.

```
Failed to create instance of driver class org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect, trying j
dbcUrl resolution

java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect cannot be cast to class java.sql.Driver (org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect is in unnamed module of loader org.
springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @2096442d; java.sql.Driver is in module java.sql of loader 'platform')
 org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

I've searched on resources on Internet but they all cannot help me fix my issue.

Here is my relevant codes of docker-compose.yml shown below.

```
services:

  database:
    container_name: mysql-database
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    ports:
      - "3366:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      #MYSQL_DATABASE: "springbootuser"
      MYSQL_USER: "springmicroserviceuser"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "111111"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "111111"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - "database"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10


userservice:
    image: user-service
    build:
      context: ./user-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      SERVER_PORT: "9000"
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://configserver:9191"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT: "9191"
      EUREKASERVER_URI: "http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka/"
      EUREKASERVER_PORT: "8761"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: "jdbc:mysql://database:3366/springbootuser?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Turkey"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME: "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: "springmicroserviceuser"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: "111111"
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: "update"
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge


volumes:
  db-data:
```

Here is my project link : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the value of **SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL**. Since you have configured a network, the host has to be  **mysql-database**

SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: "jdbc:mysql://**mysql-database**:3366/springbootuser?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Turkey"